# What is the meaning of "chill" & "low maintenance" in this text? Is it something negative?

Tags: word-meaning

This quotation is from a 2014 *Cosmopolitan* [blog post](http://www.cosmopolitan.com/style-beauty/fashion/advice/a18526/fashion-q-and-a-flats-versus-heels/).  The author of the answer is a young man; presumably the author of the question and most of the readers are women:

> Q: I usually wear heels because I think they're sexier, but lately I've been going for casual drinks in flats and getting hit on. Is there something to a flat shoe that's enticing, and which ones should I be wearing?
>
> A: It's possible that guys see your flats and think, "Hey, she seems **chill** and **low maintenance**." Or that they are less intimidated than they might be if you had the added height a pair of heels would normally give you. It's also possible that they never noticed your shoes in the first place and were responding to something you were not even aware of. There's really no way of knowing.

Comment: *Chill* means about the same as *cool*, but in the figurative sense. By *low maintenance* is meant that she is the type of girl that you don't need to spend hours and hours a day on to keep her satisfied and happy. She doesn't need too much affection to be happy as a (girl)friend. So no, I would not think these expressions have a negative connotation. On the contrary, they're positive!

Comment: What text are you quoting? If you quote a text, you should provide the name and, if possible, a link to it.

Answer (score 3):

*Low maintenance* as an adjective means that the person you're referring to doesn't need too much attention from her partner. If someone calls his girlfriend 'low maintenance', he means that she is 'chilled out(relaxed)', independent, doesn't really bother if he is not with her all the time or doesn't take it seriously when he doesn't surprise her with gifts on special occasions(these are just examples).

*High maintenance* is the right opposite. When someone calls a woman 'high maintenance', he means that she expects a lot from her companion/partner and her relationship. Such women are generally hard to please for they need their partner's love and affection to be explicitly displayed all the time.

In this context, 'low maintenance' is a positive attribute.